# Schedule Python Script - Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script which I would like to run at regular intervals.  I am running windows 7.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  Easiest way?

Comment: see this: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can do it in the command line as follows:

```
schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN PythonTask /TR "PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT"
```

That will create an hourly task called 'PythonTask'. You can replace HOURLY with DAILY, WEEKLY etc. 
PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE will be something like: C:\python25\python.exe. Check out more examples by writing this in the command line:

```
schtasks /?
```

Otherwise you can open the Task Scheduler and do it through the GUI.
Hope this helps.

Comment: "/RU system"
will let you have the script run even when the user is not logged in, useful for servers, etc.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the GUI from the control panel (called "scheduled tasks") to add a task, most of it should be self-explanatory, but there are two things to watch out for:

- Make sure you fill in `C:\python27\python.exe` as the program path, and the path to your script as the argument.
- If you choose `Run whether user is logged on or not` I get an error: `The directory name is invalid (0x87010B)`. Choosing `Run only when user is logged on` "solves" this issue.

This took me quite a bit to figure out ...

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  How do you see what the error is?

Comment: @endolith It's been years since I posted this answer, and don't really have a Windows machine for testing :-) From memory, I think you can see it in the same screen where you set the tasks somewhere... If you can't find it, it's probably a good topic for another question ;-) (maybe best posted on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 14):

A simple way to do this is to have a continuously running script with a delay loop. For example:

```
def doit():
    print "doing useful things here"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        doit()
        time.sleep(3600) # 3600 seconds = 1 hour
```

Then leave this script running, and it will do its job once per hour.

Note that this is just one approach to the problem; using an OS-provided service like the Task Scheduler is another way that avoids having to leave your script running all the time.

Comment: What's the advantage of this compared to Task Scheduler? Or other way around, why mess with TS, this seems cleaner and easier.

Comment: With this approach, there is no guarantee that the task is done once every hour... This only make sure there is one hour between tasks.. could make a difference if your task takes more than few seconds.