# Windows 7 Task Scheduler

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

Very new to this, and I have no idea where to start.

I want to schedule a python script using Task Scheduler in Windows 7.  When I add a "New Action", I place the following command as the script/program :

`c:\python25\python.exe`

As the argument, I add the full path to the location of my python script

`path\script.py`

Here is my script:

```
import datetime
import csv
import os

now = datetime.datetime.now()
print str(now)

os.chdir('C:/Users/Brock/Desktop/')
print os.getcwd()

writer = csv.writer(open("test task.csv", "wb"))
row = ('This is a test', str(now))
writer.writerow(row)
```

I got an error saying the script could not run.  Any help you can provide to get me up and running will be very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Brock

Comment: Although your question _contains_ code, it's not really programming related since it's more how to use a feature of Windows. Nudging this across to SU where you'll get a more targeted response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to do it properly through the GUI, but [see here for a nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7) involving the `schtasks` command.

Comment: Just realized you asked the same question and got the same answer last month.  Did the command not work?

Comment: It pointed me in the right direction - use the GUI - but the GUI isn't so straight forward.