# How do I set the location(start-in) of a python script in Task Scheduler in command line?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

It appears to be '\' at the Task Sceduler GUI. and I used the command and I want the script to open files in the same path without using absolute path.

I scheduled the task using the command:

```
schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN PythonTask /TR "PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT"
```

and the script doesn't open a database on the same folder to which Glen wrote the answer for it at [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to wrap calling Python script into batch `.bat` file. In that file you can change directory, set `PYTHONPATH` etc

Such batch is then executed via:

```
schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN PythonTask /TR "my_scheduled_task.bat"
```

In `my_scheduled_task.bat` you can call your Python script in any directory you want.

Such batch can be like:

```
c:
cd \my\dest\dir
c:\python32\python.exe c:\my\superscripts\dbsynchronizator.py
```

Comment: I scheduled the task using the command: schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN PythonTask /TR "PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT" and the script doesn't open a database on the same folder to which Glen wrote the answer for it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7 . Can you tell me how to accomplish that. I don't have enough reps to comment on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir(path)`: "Change the current working directory to the specified path."