# Quotes around quotes on the Windows command line

Tags: string, shell, batch-file, cmd

So I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7) which relates to what I would like to do; however, I am having trouble with the directory having spaces within it. I tried looking at several other Stack Overflow questions, but either I misunderstood them, or none have really addressed my problem. I've seen stuff on passing arguments as arrays and using `%1` or something to address the special characters, but nothing has worked yet.

I tried entering the following into cmd.exe:

```
schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN PythonTask /TR "python "C:\Users\me\stuff   with  spaces  \pythonprogram.py""
```

However, the quotes appear to not be taken in the correct order. I would like the command to be input as `python "C:\Users\me\stuff  with  spaces  \pythonprogram.py"` to cmd.exe everyday.

How can I use quotes around quotes on the Windows command line?

**ANSWER FROM BELOW:**

Add a backslash `\` before the argument which you are putting in quotes. I.e.:

```
do_some_command_in_windows_shell_with_this_given_string "run "something.exe""
```

is replaced with:

```
do_some_command_in_windows_shell_with_this_given_string "run \"something.exe""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Educated guess:

Escape the inner quotes with a backslash.

Comment: Aha! I feel like an idiot now.  Thank you very much.  I just added one backslash before the 2nd argument like so:
`schtasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN PythonTask /TR "python \"C:\Users\me\stuff   with  spaces  \pythonprogram.py""`  if anyone runs into the same problem and can understand my example.