# Is there a way to add a task to the windows task scheduler via python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a main python script that generates a GUI, and through that GUI I want the user to be able to create, amend, and delete schedules managed by the windows task scheduler.

Comment: Is using either WMI or schtasks.exe an option ?

Comment: Ahem... quick google results : http://blog.ziade.org/2007/11/01/scheduling-tasks-in-windows-with-pywin32/   http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytaskscheduler/ Have a nice day :-)

Comment: This looks like it was written for Python 2.3, so not exactly what I was looking for. Will see if I can scavenge from it though.

Comment: With `subprocess` you could do: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2725908/660921

Comment: @FredP, your solution is incompatible with 3.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also needed a way to use Python to schedule a task in Windows 10.  I discovered something simpler, using only [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and PowerShell's [`Scheduled Tasks cmdlets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=windowsserver2019-ps), which is more powerful as it gives you finer control over the task to schedule.

And there's no need for a third-party module for this one.

```py
import subprocess

# Use triple quotes string literal to span PowerShell command multiline
STR_CMD = """
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "C:\\path\\to\\file.ps1"
$description = "Using PowerShell's Scheduled Tasks in Python"
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter (New-TimeSpan -Seconds 2)
$taskName = "Test Script"
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddSeconds(10)
$trigger.EndBoundary = (Get-Date).AddSeconds(30).ToString("s")
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Description $description -Action $action -Settings $settings -Trigger $trigger | Out-Null
"""

# Use a list to make it easier to pass argument to subprocess
listProcess = [
    "powershell.exe",
    "-NoExit",
    "-NoProfile",
    "-Command",
    STR_CMD
]

# Enjoy the magic
subprocess.run(listProcess, check=True)
```

Answer (score 17):

This code creates a task which will run in 5 minutes (uses [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/)):

```
import datetime
import win32com.client

scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
scheduler.Connect()
root_folder = scheduler.GetFolder('\\')
task_def = scheduler.NewTask(0)

# Create trigger
start_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
TASK_TRIGGER_TIME = 1
trigger = task_def.Triggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME)
trigger.StartBoundary = start_time.isoformat()

# Create action
TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0
action = task_def.Actions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
action.ID = 'DO NOTHING'
action.Path = 'cmd.exe'
action.Arguments = '/c "exit"'

# Set parameters
task_def.RegistrationInfo.Description = 'Test Task'
task_def.Settings.Enabled = True
task_def.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries = False

# Register task
# If task already exists, it will be updated
TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6
TASK_LOGON_NONE = 0
root_folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(
    'Test Task',  # Task name
    task_def,
    TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
    '',  # No user
    '',  # No password
    TASK_LOGON_NONE)
```

More info on tasks and their properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-objects

Answer (score 11):

Just to round out the option list here...  How about just calling the windows command line?

```
import os

os.system(r'SchTasks /Create /SC DAILY /TN "My Task" /TR "C:mytask.bat" /ST 09:00')
```

You can launch any executable, batch file, or even another python script - assuming the system is set to execute python...

schtasks has a rich list of options and capabilities...https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks

Answer (score 9):

PyWin32 provides an interface to the Task Scheduler in `win32com.taskscheduler`. You can see an example of it's use here:

- https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/master/lib/x32/win32comext/taskscheduler/test/test_addtask_1.py

Also @FredP linked to a good example that's much simpler:

- http://blog.ziade.org/2007/11/01/scheduling-tasks-in-windows-with-pywin32/

There is also an interesting tidbit in the wmi module's cookbook about scheduling a job, although it doesn't appear to use the Task Scheduler:

- http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#schedule-a-job

Comment: Warning: Do not use the WMI method. The service which it depends on seems to be deprecated and not enabled by default (Though you can enable it via registry) since Windows 8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-scheduledjob

Answer (score 0):

I approached the problem differently. First, I manually created the desired task in Windows Task Scheduler and then exported it to an XML file. Using this XML file as a baseline, I adapted it in my code to suit dynamic requirements.
If your goal is to deploy and use the script on a different PC, you should dynamically fetch the username to set the UserId in the XML content for the task. This ensures that the task is created under the correct user account on the target machine.

```
import os
import subprocess


# Get the current username
username = os.getlogin()

    
# Generating the XML content for the task, replacing the UserId with the fetched username
xml_content = f"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <!-- ... Ensure you replace 'UserId' with the value of {username} ... -->
</Task>
"""  # You may need to modify or complete the XML content as per your requirements, especially replacing the UserId.

# Creating a regular XML file in the current directory
xml_file_name = "task_schedule.xml"
xml_file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), xml_file_name)

# Writing the XML content to the file
with open(xml_file_path, "w", encoding="UTF-16") as file:
    file.write(xml_content)

def create_task_from_xml(xml_path, task_name):
    """ 
    Create a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler using an XML file.
    Parameters:
    - xml_path (str): Path to the XML file.
    - task_name (str): Name of the task to be created.
    Returns:
    - stdout (str): Output from the schtasks command.
    - stderr (str): Error (if any) from the schtasks command.
    """
    cmd = ['schtasks', '/create', '/xml', xml_path, '/tn', task_name]
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    return result.stdout, result.stderr

task_name = "YourTaskName"
stdout, stderr = create_task_from_xml(xml_file_path, task_name)

# Deleting the XML file after creating the task
os.remove(xml_file_path)

if stderr:
    print(f"Error occurred: {stderr}")
else:
    print(f"Task '{task_name}' created successfully. Output: {stdout}")
```

With this approach, you can use the exported XML from Task Scheduler as a template and dynamically adapt it to different user accounts on different machines, allowing you to easily modify and adapt tasks programmatically.