# Why python code to run a file on startup is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I want my python file to run if Windows is booted up every single time, so I used this simple code:
**Background.py** (This creates a `.bat` file which will run my desired `.py` file on every windows startup)

```
import getpass
import os
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()

def add_to_startup():
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Python programs\testing.py %*')

add_to_startup()
```

**And this is the `.py` file which I want to run every time:**

```
with open(r"C:\Users\intel\Desktop\hello.txt", "w+") as test_file:
    test_file.write(r'start')
```

But it's not working even if my computer is on :(

**Edit 1:**
I checked The startup folder also and the `open.bat` file is successfully created and existing... 
(You can even check in the image)
[image: check the image]
    enter code here

Comment: Did you had a look there: https://superuser.com/questions/954950/run-a-script-on-start-up-on-windows-10

Comment: Yes. And the file is already created...

Comment: Personally, i prefer the 'Scheduled Tasks' method :)

Comment: Haha no, I want the every startup one :)

Comment: Read the answers again, the 'Scheduled Tasks' method is executing your script at startup , too. It's way easier to debug (and you can trigger manually) for testing.

Comment: sidenote: have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to avoid haveing to use raw string, double backslashes and the like.

Comment: @Maurice-Meyer Is there a way to do that through python? I mean I want the program to do this by itself without any manual clicks...

Comment: @Roxanne, you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160900/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-task-to-the-windows-task-scheduler-via-python-3.