# Is there a way to remove a task to the windows task scheduler via python?

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I successfully created task in Task Scheduler. I know how to disable it but I cannot find a way completely remove it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for being late... I just fought with this issue.
Firstly i learn how to create a task using this [this good snippet from **xuhcc** on another question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160900/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-task-to-the-windows-task-scheduler-via-python-3) After i searched for about 40 minutes on Microsoft`s site, i just got it and it works.

Here is a little part of my code:

```py
def deleteWindowsTask(updatetask_id):
    obj = UpdateTask.objects.get(pk=updatetask_id)

    scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch('Schedule.Service')
    scheduler.Connect()
    root_folder = scheduler.GetFolder('\\')

    root_folder.DeleteTask(obj.task_name,0) 
...
```

basicaly everything here is a Task Scheduler scripting object and you can modify them by using the following [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-objects)

in my case the "root_folder" in the language of "Task Scheduler scripting object" is the *TaskFolder* object as you can see [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/taskfolder)