# how to execute a program for every ten mins for the entire day in Python

Tags: python, windows, web-crawler

I am working on web crawler app to download the stock price every ten minutes. I am able to extract the quote but I am not sure how to schedule it to run every ten minutes for the entire day. 
Please suggest me either time loop kind of a thing or the solution for the web crawler app itself.
I need a solution which works on Windows.

Comment: Add it to as a cronjob.

Comment: @badc0re say suppose i have to print 'hi' every secs for one min. so      def f(): print('hi'). how do I run this function ?

Comment: Yeah best would be to run this script as cronjob..

Comment: @badc0re how about in Windows

Comment: @Shiva, You may look at a scheduler in windows which is similar to cron in linux. It runs periodically at whatever the time interval you set it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195503/setting-up-a-cron-job-in-windows

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so you have a python function f() which you want to execute every ten mins for a day. You can do this:

```
import time
while True: #Infinite loop
    f() #Execute the function
    time.sleep(600) #Wait 600s (10 min) before re-entering the cycle
```

And you keep the script running for as long as you need (a day, a week, whatever, it will not close by itself)

Comment: This answer ignores the running time of f(). If f() takes 1 min to run, it will be executed only every 11 min.

Comment: I didn't understand that from the question, but indeed, my answer executes f() every ten minutes plus the execution time.

Comment: @francisco  I am not getting the output but there are no errors too :(

Comment: Can you show the code of the function? Or at least give more details as to what it outputs.

Answer (score 1):

you can do try this

```
import time
```

and but this code before dawnload method

```
time.sleep(10*60) #this will stop the program for 10 minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use crontab. Open the crontab file via terminal:

```
$ crontab -e
```

At the end of the file you can set the python script and the frequency of running it. For example to run a script every 10 mins:

```
*/10 * * * * /path/to/script
```

Comment: I am running  the program in windows!

Comment: time.sleep(10*60) works also, but not suggested. if you restart your computer it will not start only if you run it manually.

Comment: @ barney let me day I have a function 'f'. how do I execute it after every ten seconds. Can you please let me know the code ?

Comment: i think there is no crontab for windows. :(

Comment: Note that this solution is limited to a script runtime smaller than 10 minutes because the scheduler does not know about job completion.

Comment: i think if the runtime of the script is longer then 10mins, then the crontab will start a new process and let the previous script run till it ends.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a Task Scheduler built-in. You can use that to run your script:

- http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/
- [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)

Otherwise, you can write an infinite loop that will check the stock prices every ten minutes using something like `time.sleep(600)`. Note that you can add your program to run at startup fairly easily:

- https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2013-April/094756.html
- [how to start a python file while window starts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438020/how-to-start-a-python-file-while-window-starts)