# Flask APScheduler - Cron Job only happens with active users on the page

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler

I have a low traffic internal webpage for which we use for the management of remote computers.

This webpage attempts to register a CRON job, so that once a week at a specified time, an e-mail will be sent to a list, with the current status of the data from the database.

However, in testing, everything appeared fine. When pushing to production, I would test the cron job, it would work. But when leaving the system running over the weekend ( when possibly no one is on the system), the job does not get executed.

I have tried initializing in a few different ways, so that it wouldn't (shouldn't) be tied to any requests on the system, and should register at initialization, regardless of if anyone has hit the system.

### mmsver.wsgi

```
from flask_apscheduler.scheduler import APScheduler
from nydps.web.mmserver import app as application

scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(application)
scheduler.start()
```

### mmserver.py (excerpt)

```
def weekly_report():
    # doing things with a session
    # send_smtp is a custom smtp function
    send_smtp(smtp_content, destination, smtpSender, 'TMM Directory: Weekly Utilization Report')

app.config['JOBS'] = [{
    'id': 'weekly_report',
    'func': weekly_report,
    'trigger': {
        'type': 'cron',
        'day_of_week': weekly_report_day_of_week,
        'hour': weekly_report_hour,
        'minute': weekly_report_minute
    }
}]
```

If I go change the report day, hour, minute. Restart the server, it will execute. Only when I set the day hour minute to a time in the slightly further future (where I am not actively on the site), it doesnt appear to be executed.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Production is deployed behind Apache using WAMP on Windows.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back with django on Linux.  The issue was that Apache log rotation restarted the web server, but didn't restart the wsgi application until it got a request for it.  Could you be hitting the same?

Comment: Thanks for the input, that's very interesting. I do have log rotation enabled with apache, but I'm not sure how that interacts with restarting the web server? I guess the logical conclusion would be to test it with log rotation off, I will have to try it later this week.

Comment: I was on vacation this past week but I certainly have not forgotton about this thread. Unfortunately, it seems to have missed its scheduled appointment (saturday off time) even with log rotation disabled. I was really hoping to limit any added complexity with things like task scheduler since I have to sell it by a support staff first, some more time with the problem at hand before I go that route I think.

Comment: At this point, all I can think of is to try [catching the Python interpreter shutdown](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/RegisteringCleanupCode.wiki#Cleanup_On_Process_Shutdown) and seeing when it gets terminated, then following it back from there...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it is not a good idea to used Apache + Webapp to run scheduled tasks.

If your are under Windows, why don't you add a task on the Task Scheduler?
You can run Python scripts (using a BAT script).

1. Create a standalone Python application,
2. Deploy the application on Windows,
3. Create a new task in the Task Scheduler.

## Create a standalone Python application

You can develop on Linux or Windows, but you need to prepare your release on Windows:

First, install Python on Windows, with `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel`.
Add `C:\{PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR}\Scripts` to your `PATH` for simplicity.

As administrator, create your target directory structure in `C:\Program Files\{YOUR_COMPANY}`.

With a MS-DOS console, create a virtualenv and activate it:

```
C:
CD C:\Program Files\{YOUR_COMPANY}
virtualenv {YOUR_APP_NAME}
{YOUR_APP_NAME}\Scripts\activate
```

Install your application:

```
pip install {YOUR_APP_NAME}   # if on PyPi
pip install {YOUR_WHEEL}      # if on another source (ex.: a file)
```

Now, you can compress the `C:\Program Files\{YOUR_COMPANY}` folder in a ZIP file and publish it: ex.: "{YOUR_APP_NAME}-py2-win64.zip".

## Deploy the application on Windows

On windows, download your ZIP file "{YOUR_APP_NAME}-py2-win64.zip" and uncompress it.

As administrator, copy the uncompressed folder `{YOUR_COMPANY}\{YOUR_APP_NAME}` to `C:\Program Files\{YOUR_COMPANY}`.

Run your installation script if you have one, or update configuration files.

## Create a new task in the Task Scheduler

- Detail article on Microsoft TechNet: [Schedule a Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx),
- This question: [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7),
- This blog: [Scheduling a Python script](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/),

The Python executable path will be:

```
"C:\Program Files\{YOUR_COMPANY}\{YOUR_APP_NAME}\Scripts\python.exe"
```

You can also consider your entry point if you declare one in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you complicating the issue by trying to launch a cron job like this? Just save the hassle and write directly to the crontab with python-crontab:

```
from crontab import CronTab 
cron = CronTab(user = True) #user='username' to specify a different account

job = cron.new(command='python /home/usr/script/script.py')
job.week.every(1)
job.enable()
if job.is_enabled():
    print 'success!'
```

Comment: The docs are quite vague on this. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/ - why are you running WAMP on Windows for production?

Comment: Support staff doesn't have Linux training (lol) and WAMP is the Windows packaging version

Comment: A quick look at the [source](https://git.launchpad.net/python-crontab/tree/crontab.py) shows that it requires a valid cron installation to work.  I reckon that means you need something like cygwin...

Comment: Another possibility is this pure python replacement for os scheduling services http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/

Comment: @cal97g But that's what the OP is already using (wrapped for Flask) and isn't working...

Comment: python-crontab will run as a process on windows, see documentation "Running the Scheduler" suggestions for improvements welcome.