# Getting logged off while running python script (Windows)

Tags: python, windows

I have a script that takes a very long time to run and processes a bunch of files. However, if I'm inactive for a period of time (around 15 minutes) I get logged off and the script terminates. I don't have permissions to change the settings to stop myself from getting logged off. Is there anything I can do to keep the script running without having to manually move the mouse?

Comment: Write a second script using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181464/controlling-mouse-with-python

Comment: ^^^ what he said. Mouse jiggler to the rescue.

Comment: I think it will continue running if its a scheduled task but don't have a Windows machine handy to test. Run `Task Scheduler` and use it to start the program, use the command line `schtask`  as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7, or perhaps python WMI bindings.

Comment: You may have better luck on serverfault.com