# Unable to run my python script through windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

I have installed the anaconda package and been running python notebooks and python scripts easily directly from console. I created a script and want it to run every day at particular time period but it did not work. So I created a simple test file to check what is wrong. This is my test file

```
print("enter the no to exit")
input()
```

When I run this program on command prompt it ask me for an input and then it exit.

I followed this tutorial to run this program daily using windows scheduler https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/

In action tab I wrote this

"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe"

And the argument as

"E:\test.py"

And when I run the task manually a black window pop up and automatically closed, I cannot figure out what is wrong. I see it say something like invalid directory. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into [this thread from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7):

> You can do it in the command line as follows:
>
> `schtasks /Create /SC HOURLY /TN PythonTask /TR "PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE PATH_TO_PYTHON_SCRIPT"`
>
> That will create an hourly task called 'PythonTask'. You can replace HOURLY with DAILY, WEEKLY etc. PATH_TO_PYTHON_EXE will be something like: C:\python25\python.exe. Check out more examples by writing this in the command line:
>
> `schtasks /?`
>
> Otherwise you can open the Task Scheduler and do it through the GUI. Hope this helps.

This might solve your problem.

If it is **still not working** you may refer to [this thread from esri](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51613).
This will get your job done.

Comment: I did what you said. I created the task and the task was successfully created. As I mentioned in my question as well, I am able to create the task but it is not executing, a black window pops up and then goes away without asking me to input something

Comment: I am using anaconda 3 and my python executable path is "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe" and my script path is "C:\Users\NITIN\test.py"

Comment: Thank you. I was missing quotations in my argument. Silly mistake.

Comment: If my answer does what you need then please mark it correct else please do comment.

Comment: Please add thread you posted in comment in your answer so that I can mark it as complete.

Answer (score 2):

To run Python programs in Task Manager on Windows: In "Programs/Script" input path to python.exe In "Add Arguments"input script file name In "Additional Information" input path to location where file is saved

For example:

Path to Python: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Python.exe

Script name ./script.py

Path to location where script is saved: C:/foldername/

Answer (score 2):

Add the following command in beginning of the .bat file where all the configuration of python and python script written

```
CD /d %~dp0
```

**In my case .bat file looks like**

```
CD /d %~dp0 
Call "C:\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "D:\myProject\script.py" 
pause
```