# Make a program restart regulary

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a project that I want to restart and rerun every 10 minutes. So I created this test file to see if I could get it working.

```
import sys
import os
import sched
import time

print("Hello")
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def restart_program(sc):
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
    s.enter(5, 1, restart_program, (sc,))

s.enter(5, 1, restart_program, (s,))
s.run()
```

So I want this program to restart every 5 seconds. In this case it would print "Hello!". But when i run it, it just prints once and never restarts.

How would I make it restart regulary?

Comment: use a cron job?

Comment: you can use loop & timeout in python to get it done.

Comment: Yeah, this is really what `cron` is designed for.

Comment: As Sneh Pandya said. you can use simple loop with timeout. I think there is no reason to use cron until you really dont have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what exactly are you looking for but below are the 3 possible cases.

1: If the program is running (perhaps as a daemon?) and you want to keep calling a particular method after some interval then you can use [apscheduler](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def do_something_every_5_second():
    print "Do something"

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(do_something_every_5_second, 'interval', seconds=5)
scheduler.start()
```

2: You can use [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which will execute your python script at defined time. Note that Cron can not be set for less than 1 minute. So for eg if you want to run your script through Cron every 5 seconds then you'll have to use below hack.

```
* * * * * /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 5; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 10; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 15; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 20; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 25; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 30; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 35; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 40; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 45; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 50; /path/to/script
* * * * * sleep 55; /path/to/script
```

If you are on Windows then you can use Windows Task Scheduler. See [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)

3: You can use loop with timeout ([as suggested by Sneh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43673541/make-a-program-restart-regulary/43673958#comment74393215_43673541))

Answer (score 0):

Besides some possibilities for better choices, I think your code does not work because of the behaviour of [os.execl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl):

> These functions all execute a new program, replacing the current process; they do not return.

check out [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

```
   import sched
   import time
   import subprocess

   print("Hello")
   s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

   def restart_program(sc):
       subprocess.Popen(["echo", "external process is being called"])
       s.enter(5, 1, restart_program, (sc,))

   s.enter(5, 1, restart_program, (s,))
   s.run()
```