# Excute a python script in a Google Sheet file

Tags: python, drive

I would like to execute a Python script every time I add a value in a Google Sheet cell. I'd put a keyword in a cell, my already made Python script would crawl on YouTube for videos and would fill the next cells with the best video links.

I already succeed to connect my Python script to my Google Sheet but I have to run the script on my computer after modifying the sheet. I would like to make it automatic.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7