# setup a cron job in django in windows

Tags: django, cron

I want to setup `cronjob` in my `Django` project, but I am using `windows`.
I tried `django-cron`, but it is not working with `windows`.

How can I use `cronjob` scheduling in my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)

Answer (score 4):

Using django-cron is not the case and cannot be used on Windows, because **Windows do not support cron** job scheduling. You can use Windows analog of the Unix cron command called "[schtasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/schtasks)" to schedule execution of your script or [Windows Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx).

See more in SO Questions [What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron) and [Schedule Python Script - Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725754/schedule-python-script-windows-7)