# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl' on windows 11

Tags: django, django-crontab

**I am using Django==4.1.1 and django-crontab==0.7.1**

this error occurs when I use *crontab* on my project. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Welp, I've prob got some bad news: `The module fctnl is not available on Windows systems` ..maybe checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785215/setup-a-cron-job-in-django-in-windows -or you might be able to use Schedule Tasks if you're deadset on windows