# Using Python to Schedule a job everyday

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run a job every day at 9:55 AM to load a data frame into an Excel sheet. I was able to figure out the below code that apparently does that. However, when I run the code, it's sort of perennially stuck in execution mode without any results. I basically do not want to open Pycharm every day to run this code. What do I need to add to run the job every day without me having to do anything at all?

```
def job():
    df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(25).reshape(5, 5), index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    writer=pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
    df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()


schedule.every().day.at("09:55").do(job)

while True:
schedule.run_pending()
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I'd use a cron job on Linux or something similar on a Windows machine, given that you have a machine that runs 24/7.

Comment: I do not have a machine that runs 24/7 and I'm on Windows.

Comment: As mentioned before you can use different schedulers for Windows.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975/6244607

Comment: @LaxMandis Windows has Task Scheduler. This is something the OS can do for you, not something you program yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For scheduling tasks, you better use software which was designed to do that.
In *nix environment it could be Cron, for example.
For Win* -- probably TaskScheduler.
Anyway, you probably would like to take this approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2725908/2822774

Answer (score 0):

i had a simmilar problem - u can see my py_scheduler library for it
https://github.com/kl09/py_scheduler
This is better to controll schduler job in your app, to make a special microservice for it, neither to use a cron